# Установить макс и мин год для DatePicker

Tags: ios, swift

Задача заключается в том, чтобы установить минимальный и максимальный год для `DatePicker`. Мой код:

```
let gregorian: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!  

let currentDate: Date = Date()
 let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()

 components.year = -30
 let minDate: Date = gregorian.date(byAdding: components as DateComponents, to: currentDate, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))!

 components.year = 5
 let maxDate: Date = gregorian.date(byAdding: components as DateComponents, to: currentDate, options: NSCalendar.Options(rawValue: 0))!

 datePicker.minimumDate = minDate
 datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate
 datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleDatePicker), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
 datePicker.setDate(Date(), animated: true)
```

Устанавливаем год от -30 до 5 лет. Не подходит потому что число и дата сбиваются когда мы настраиваем год. 
Еще не подходит потому что года которые выходят за рамки установленного не исчезают, а просто становятся не активными.

Comment: То есть Вам надо, чтобы в случае если пользователь пролистал список дат вниз на 5 лет вперёд он не мог листать далее? Чтобы datePicker останавливался в этот момент?

Comment: непонятно почему у вас дата сбивается (она будет сбиваться только если выставить максимальный год). На второй вопрос - да они не активны и выбрать их нельзя, если вы хотите убрать их сделайте свой пикер в который вставьте года которые вам нужны

Comment: @RomanPodymov да, именно так.

Comment: @AndreyIskamov как я понял без кастового пикера не обойтись ?

Comment: @КеримХасбулатов Мне кажется Вашу проблему стандартным UIDatePicker решить нельзя. А Вам точно надо именно его останавливать в определённый момент? Чем Вас не устроило стандартное поведение в данной ситуации?

Comment: @RomanPodymov заказчик хотел, поэтому начал искать решение. В любом случае, если кому нужно будет установить максимальный и минимальный год. То решение которое я указал выше поможет. За исключеним того что другие года будут не активны, но в то же время юзер будет их видеть.

Comment: @КеримХасбулатов Но ведь Вашему заказчику почему-то надо эти даты не просто делать неактивными, а убирать их полностью из UIDatePicker. Неужели настолько точно указаны требования?

Comment: @RomanPodymov да :)